# GitHub Actions workflow for Python project on Google Cloud Build/Run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, github-actions, gcloud

I have a Python/Django project deployed on GCP Cloud Run. To deploy it, I use a gcloud config file `cloudbuild.yaml` which builds then pushes the image using `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`, then executes some project-specific Python commands using `gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper`.

I'm trying to convert that as a GitHub Actions workflow but I don't know about the steps to execute project-specific Python commands in the container built by Google Cloud.

What would be the equivalent steps than the ones using `gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper` for that in a GitHub Actions YAML workflow?

The gcloud config file `cloudbuild.yaml` looks like this:

```
# [START cloudrun_django_cloudmigrate]
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}", "."]

  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"]

  - id: "apply migrations"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "migrate",
      ]
    secretEnv: ['ENVIRONMENT', 'SECRET_KEY', 'DATABASE_URL', 'GS_BUCKET_NAME']

  - id: "collect static"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "collectstatic",
        "--verbosity",
        "2",
        "--no-input",
      ]
    secretEnv: ['ENVIRONMENT', 'SECRET_KEY', 'DATABASE_URL', 'GS_BUCKET_NAME']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/ENVIRONMENT/versions/latest
    env: 'ENVIRONMENT'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_KEY/versions/latest
    env: 'SECRET_KEY'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DATABASE_URL/versions/latest
    env: 'DATABASE_URL'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/GS_BUCKET_NAME/versions/latest
    env: 'GS_BUCKET_NAME'

substitutions:
  _INSTANCE_NAME: my-db-instance
  _REGION: europe-west9
  _SERVICE_NAME: my-project

images:
  - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"
# [END cloudrun_django_cloudmigrate]
```

Comment: See [Publishing Docker images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images).